# No css found and admin url not found on this server magento 2

Tags: magento2, css

I have added my project on a virtual machine amazon and when I try to get my FO I have no CSS and when I click on any link example category I get an **error**

> The requested URL /Siteindex.php/customer/account/create/ was not
>   found on this server.

and can't recuperate my admin URL not found on this server any help, please

Comment: Have you checked whether **`mod_rewrite`** is working or not in the server?

Comment: yes it's enabled

Comment: and web/seo/use_rewrites is set to 1